# setting <figure> width dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a figure tag whose width I am trying to set by the .css function of the jQuery API according to the browser width. Here's the code:

```
var browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
$('.span13').css("width",browserWidth);
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: The device width, the screen width, the browser width or the documents width, they are not all the same ?

Comment: So, what does not work?

Comment: @Bergi The width is not set properly

Comment: Are you trying to get this to update when the browser is resized ?

Comment: Did you try `$('.span13').css("width", $(window).width());`

Answer (score 0):

You could just do "100vw". "vw" is a unit of 1/100 of browser width.

Comment: jQuery will assume pixels if nothing else is specified.